# Robocopy reporting wrong file count on log summary

Tags: robocopy

I’m copying a folder with robocopy and it’s copying-over just fine.  However, the file count reported at bottom is wrong (see picture)
To make sure it copied fine, I opened the log with Word and searched for the string   “    same “  which reported the right amount of copied files.
After some testing, I noticed that it is the multithread switch “/MT:32” that is producing the issue, so when I don’t use the switch, the file count is correct.  I tried removing other switches with unreliable results: /L, /V (this one sometimes gave the right count).
This is the command I used:
ROBOCOPY "F:\USERS\ANTON\ONEDRIVE" E:\ONEDRIVETEST16 /MIR /R:0 /MT:32 /NP /L /V /LOG:E:\ONEDRIVETEST16
Any idea why /MT maybe doing that?
Any hints much welcome
[image]
[image]

Comment: In a multi-threading environment the developer has to take special care that not two threads increase the counter at the same time and so one increase is lost. May be developer of robocopy at Microsoft did not implement thread synchronization in the correct way for the summary counter. You are using robocopy included in Windows 10? Which Windows version do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 21H1.  You may be right, I suspect something of that sort.  Super Thanks for your answer.